# How to avoid "wants to open" dialog triggered by openURL in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I use openURL to open **app B** from **App A**, and I get this alert dialog "**App A** wants to open **App B**", with two buttons, "Open" and "Cancel".

If I press "Cancel", **app B** won't open and dialog will appear again.

If I press "Open", **app B** will open and dialog won't appear again.

I would like to somehow to make it not appear to begin with. I am wondering if there is a key I should add to **app A**'s info.plist in order to skip the dialog step when doing openURL to **app B**.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

After checking, I could not come up with a solution for my problem. It looks like this dialog will appear regardless. I hope Apple will add the option to handle it automatically as if both apps are mine, logically, there should not be any dialog to confirm switching between them...

Comment: Hey Roy, would be great if you update the title of your question to be in a question form. I am not sure what you're really asking, the current title is more of an observation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking for hours, I could not come up with a solution for my problem. It looks like this dialog will appear regardless anything... I hope Apple will add the option to handle it in the app's info.plist as if both apps are mine, logically, there should not be any dialog to confirm switching between them...

Comment: I too need to skip that dialog in order to move between my own apps freely. I'd be happy to know if you find a solution.

Comment: @RoyK can we show this alert each time for testing?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.macstories.net/linked/ios-9-bringing-changes-to-url-schemes/

> Starting on iOS 9, apps will have to declare what URL schemes they would like to be able to check for and open in the configuration files of the app as it is submitted to Apple. This is essentially a whitelist that can only be changed or added to by submitting an update to Apple.

openURL / canOpenURL has changed in iOS9 due to user privacy. I suggest you read http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes

The user will now see this prompt the first time you ask for permission as per other permission requests. This is an OS change and apps, including core applications such as messages now ask for permission when opening a custom URL scheme for the first time.

You also may be able to achieve what you are trying to do using Universal Links - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12

Comment: Thanks, I added iOS 9 remark. However, this did not answer my question. I am aware of this new dialog, but not sure how to make it not appear...

Comment: It will appear only the first time the each app calls the respective URL scheme, are you saying it shows every time? Have you added the scheme's to the plist via the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key?

Comment: It does not shows every time, however, I am trying to avoid it even for the first time... Adding LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array to info.plist has nothing to do with it. It will only allow canOpenURL method to check if the listed url schema's are installed on the device. It won't change the behavior of this specific dialog.

Comment: Then, I'm not sure sorry! I think You have to show the dialog the first time round. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: For me, every time I click on a YouTube link from Safari, this dialog appears.

Comment: Does any one know a way to reset the phone to cause the prompt to appear again? I need this for testing. It seems like once you accept 1x, there is no way to trigger the prompt to appear again, even if you delete and reinstall both apps.

Comment: @derrrick In order to get this alerts again, reset device data and settings :) that is the only way to get them back.