# Issues getting Meteor data into React Native using createContainer

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-native

I can't seem to get createContainer to work with React Native and Meteor data. I'm currently using the [react-native-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-meteor) package and the latest releases of Meteor/React Native. I've reviewed the info for the package and Meteor's official write-up of createContainer. I guess first off, I'm not really sure how this container works. It looks like it wraps the component called at the end and updates it when the reactive data changes?

I've tried it a few different ways but below is what I currently am using. I'm not sure if createContainer is even getting called, as I don't see anything in the console from my log statement. I've tried using Meter.user() and Meteor.userId() as well with no luck. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { loginToSpotify } from './react-native-spotify-auth'
import Meteor, { createContainer } from 'react-native-meteor'
//import { testComponent } from './component'

//TODO: openURL bug on iOS9 causes iOS to confirm before redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312009/how-to-avoid-wants-to-open-dialog-triggered-by-openurl-in-ios-9-0
//May also want to look into using Universal  links

Meteor.connect('http://localhost:3000/websocket');//do this only once

class ReactNativeApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      access_token: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    loginToSpotify();
  }

  render() {
    const { todosReady } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
        <Text>
          Hello {!todosReady && <Text>Not Ready</Text>}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(params=>{
  const handle = Meteor.subscribe('todos');
  console.log('todos: ' + Meteor.collection('todos').find());
  return {
    todosReady: handle.ready()
  }
}, ReactNativeApp);



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeApp', () => ReactNativeApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you see in console that meteor connected to the app? You shouldn't use http in Meteor.connect anymore, instead ws://localhost:3000/websocket

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure that your meteor application is running.
2. Use the IP of your local machine, don't use localhost. If you are using mobile as emulator that's good. Connect both in Router and use your machine language.

For more information you can follow this [React Native Meteor Boilerplate](https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-meteor-boilerplate).