# iOS deeplinks in safari not opened automatically

Tags: ios, deep-linking

While browsing safari site I am accessing the urls that are to be handled by the app (using deeplinks).

- The "open in app" banner is being shown on each of sites and I am properly redirected to the app when tapped (even after I've already selected the open in the app previously).
- when tapping the link in notes/email/etc. the app is properly opened.

Is it possible to automatically redirect to app when tapping the handled link when browsing in safari? (I am not 100% sure, but I think it was working like this previously).

- apple-app-site-association file is set properly (otherwise the app won't recognise the links in any way).

Comment: You mean skipping the "Open in App Name" popup?

Comment: @David exactly - just automatically redirect to the app using the url that is to be opened

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's handled by the OS and is impossible to bypass. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312009/how-to-avoid-wants-to-open-dialog-triggered-by-openurl-in-ios-9-0

Comment: Well, that's sad. But thanks! Not sure why does I had a feeling it was previously working like that.